# How to deal with javascript internationalization

Tags: javascript, internationalization, yii

Is there any mechanism in yii framework to translate messages in javascript source files.

For example with:

```
yiic message config-message.php
```

I can generate translation .php files for all Yii::t().

Is it possible to generate .js files with the same mechanism. Currently I'm including to my javascript json data with table returned by translation file.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution would be to make Yii include translated messages in the DOM, that will be later accessed by your JS code, so:

1. You do not need to repeat JS code.
2. Translation is centralized in the PHP/Yii framework.

Answer (score 4):

I've created an extension that should handle this:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jstrans/

Answer (score 2):

It's a really problem. Multi languages sites is always problem. YII solve the problem for php code. But js code problem still on place.

I do not very elegant solution but it's works. Create controller/component and generate js code with localization on the fly using t().

/js/get/?file=some-js-file
in layout:

Of course, every JS need to be rewrite. If use small pieces of code (cs()->RegisterScript) I use t() as well.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled over this problem and using a controller to generate js code on the fly is not an option because you will waste resources because of starting an additional PHP process on every request. This may be a problem on high traffic sites.
So I implemented a different approach:
In the .js messages are stored in Variables e.g.

```
var MyJsClass = {
    lang:
    {
        foo: 'Foo',
        bar: 'Bar',
    },
    doSomething: function()
    {
        console.log(this.lang.foo);
    },  
};
```

in the view you add the translation if the current language is different to the sourceLanguage of the App:

```
<?php
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->registerScriptFile($this->module->assetsUrl.'/js/myjsclass.js');
if (Yii::app()->sourceLanguage != Yii::app()->language) {
    $cs->registerScript('MyScriptID', '
        MyJsClass.lang.foo = \''.Yii::t('TranslationCategory', 'Translated Foo').'\';
        MyJsClass.lang.bar = \''.Yii::t('TranslationCategory', 'Translated Bar').'\';
    ');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way to deal with that issue.

You can for example generate file with an array in with 'message-id' => 'translation' and include the correct one and then do stuff like alert($messages['itemDeleted']) or something.

An alternative could be to make views of your javascript and use the Yii::t() function on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way of doing it.

Little context for my application :

- Available languages differ from one section to another, and is available through the `$availableLanguages` variable.
- I have created very small message files to be able to make public some of them without any security issue. I then created a variable called `$langFiles` that I can change within the controller.

```php
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;

$files = FileHelper::findFiles(\Yii::getAlias('@app/messages/'));
$translations = [];

// Loop into all the available languages
foreach($availableLanguages as $lang) {
    $translations[$lang] = [];

    // Get all the available message files
    foreach ($langFiles as $file) {

        // Import the php file if it exists
        $filePath = \Yii::getAlias("@app/messages/{$lang}/{$file}.php");
        $key = "app/{$file}";

        $translations[$lang][$key] = file_exists($filePath) ? include($filePath) : [];

        // Replace '.' by '_' to use the get method
        foreach($translations[$lang][$key] as $msg => $value) {
            unset($translations[$lang][$key][$msg]);

            $msg = str_replace('.', '_', $msg);
            $translations[$lang][$key][$msg] = $value;
        }
    }
}
?>

<script>
var translations = <?= Json::encode($translations) ?>;
var lang = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');

function t(category, message) {
    // Get method thats works exactly like lodash
    const get = (value, path, defaultValue) => {
        return String(path).split('.').reduce((acc, v) => {
            try {
                acc = acc[v];

                if(typeof acc === 'undefined') {
                    throw "Undefined";
                }
            } catch (e) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            return acc;
        }, value)
    }

    // Replace '.' by '_' to use the get method.
    var key = message.replace('.', '_');

    // If the translation is not found, return the original message
    console.log(lang+'.'+category+'.'+key, message);
    return get(translations, lang+'.'+category+'.'+key, message);
}
</script>
```

I can now get the translation directly into my scripts by using the same syntax as in Yii2. Example :

`t('app/quotes', 'Hello World. Captain speaking!')`